# Read double using fscanf

Tags: c++, c, file, scanf

I want to read double from text file
e.g.
31  39.9316476397222    116.113516352222

I tried both, not work. I can only read the first few decimal digital e.g. 39.93164 but not 39.9316476397222
anyone knows why? Thanks!

```
int NodeID;
double _lat,_long;
fscanf (pFile, "%d %lf %lf", &NodeID,&_lat,&_long);
printf ("I have read: %d %f %f\n", NodeID,_lat,_long);

fscanf (pFile, "%d %lf %lf", &NodeID,&_lat,&_long);
printf ("I have read: %d %lf %lf\n", NodeID,_lat,_long);
```

Comment: Please read the manual for what `printf` does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the numbers are read correctly. Your problem is in your printing out, which makes you think you don't have the whole number. Keep in mind that `printf` typically only outputs a few digits after the decimal point.

I suggest you do these:

1. In your `printf` calls, use a format specifier like this: "`%.20f`". It tells `printf` to output 20 digits after the decimal point.
2. Keep in mind that whatever floating-point you use, `float` or `double` or `long double`, it's going to have a limited precision and resolution. Familiarize yourself with floating-point numbers and how they work and are represented.

Comment: "%.20f" works. Thanks. I know the different between float, double and long double

Comment: @dykw: Understand that your `scanf` was working already; the problem was (and is and will be) that base-2 floating point numbers and base-10 real numbers are not the same set. You cannot represent many many many real numbers using float point; even real numbers with only a limited precision.

Answer (score 22):

According to the [fscanf man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/), you should use `%lf` for double :

> f, e, g (Floating point number) : A series of decimal digits, optionally containing a decimal point, optionally preceeded by a sign (+ or -) and optionally followed by the e or E character and a decimal integer (or some of the other sequences supported by strtod).
>   Implementations complying with C99 also support hexadecimal floating-point format when preceded by 0x or 0X.
>   [image]

Comment: Right answer, with "%f" we get a warning: format "%f" expects type "float", but argument 3 has type "double"

Comment: Worth noting is that if you output using printf( "%lf" ), fscanf will give you junk results if trying to read it as fscanf("%f").