# linked list input type problems

Tags: c++, types

I have this code where the user is asked to input a number to let the program know how big my linked list will be then the next user inputs will be the data pushed into the links. I am having no problems with integers but for whatever reason once I start using decimal points, for example 32.22, the program stops normal execution and keeps the numbers on the left side of the number with decimal point, and adds that same number to the rest of the nodes. FYI, I am developing in Visual Studio Express 2012.

For a good execution, using 3 as the number of datum and numbers 1, 2, 3, respectively, I get the following output:

```
How many numbers?
3
Please enter number
1
List is: 1
Please enter number
2
List is: 2 1
Please enter number
3
List is: 3 2 1
Press any key to continue . . . _
```

For a bad output I get this:

```
How many numbers?
3
Please enter number
1
List is: 1
Please enter number
23.23
List is: 23 1
Please enter number
List is: 23 23 1
Press any key to continue . . . _
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

 struct Node
{
    double data;
    Node* next;
    };

struct Node* head; // global variable
void Insert(double x)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL) temp->next = head; 
    head = temp;
}

void Print()
{
Node* temp = head;
printf("List is: "); 
while(temp != NULL)
{
    printf(" %d", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}
printf("\n");
}
int main()
{

head = NULL; // empty list
printf("How many numbers?\n");
int n, i;
double x;
scanf_s("%d", &n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter number \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    Insert(x);
    Print();
}
system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Any tips or suggestions on this? What bugs me is that the code works great for integers but once I start introducing decimal points it goes crazy. I have tried casting the user inputs as well as the data type in my node struct as both type int and type double and I get the same results using both.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &x);` should be `scanf_s("%lf", &x);`

Comment: `scanf`is **not type safe**. Still, if you compile with g++ you get "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double'". Instead of fixing the format specification, remove all the C level i/o and use `cin` and `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf_s("%d", &x);
```

should be

```
scanf_s("%lf", &x);
```

`%d` is for reading in a decimal integer. `%lf` is for [reading in a long floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566203/1270789), that is a `double`.

Comment: That should be `%lf` as it's a double.

Comment: @KenY-N: No. But it should be standard `scanf` instead of Microsoft `scanf_s`. However, better, it should be replaced with C++ iostreams i/o.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Check the [not accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28566203/1270789) in the dup or [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) - both say `%lf`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I changed struct Node and variable x to have data as type float opposed to double as well as using scanf("%f", &x); when punching in the numbers and finally printf(" %.8f", temp->data); for 8 decimal places. It is working like a champ now. Ken Y-N, thanks for the link to the other answer submission, :D

Comment: @KenY-N: Thanks,  you're right. That's a little inconsistency between printf and scanf that I'd forgotten about. Many many years since used scanf. :)